# How does this work with textboxes in win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am learning C#, for my school homeworks. I suddenly try to do something and I thought, I am going to get a bug in the below  code

```
  private void ClearControls()
        {
            this.textBox1 .Text = "";
            this.textBox1 = this.textBox2 = this.textBox3 = this.textBox4;
        }
```

Wow...it works better what I expected and it cleared all my text  boxes in the form , and before this, I was doing like

```
textBox1 .Text = "";
textBox2 .Text = "";
```

and so on till some twenty text boxes in a form (this is the method , my teacher told me and all my classmates follow this :(  )..

which one is correct, and why the first one works good and how the default attribute assigned to a textbox is always text and not name or tabindex or someother ones ?

if the question is not clear or a little mess, please tell and I will try change it.

Thanks for taking time to clear my doubts :D

Comment: Pro tip: Name your controls. You won't find it funny when you have to double-check every other line of code if the description of the car is in textbox17 or in textbox23.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite. This line sets each reference equal to textBox4, which is not what you want.  Now these four references all point to the same thing.

```
this.textBox1 = this.textBox2 = this.textBox3 = this.textBox4
```

What you wanted was this:

```
this.textBox1.Text = this.textBox2.Text = this.textBox3.Text = this.textBox4.Text = ""
```

However, that is a maintenance headache.  Create a UserControl for this stuff or at least maintain a collection of TextBox objects that you can iterate through to set common properties instead of adding a new line for every text box.

Comment: @Ed Swangren, if textbox1.text = "", empty everthing is getting empty and like wise textBox4.text ="Hi, Curie" is getting copied to all textboxes too, My doubt is how both assignment are working ?

Comment: @Robert: No, that is very wrong.  The compiler will not assume that you meant to assign to the text property because the rhs of the statement is a string.  You will get a compile error.

Comment: @Marie: It's not.  You have omitted code or something else is going on, but your example would not clear the text in all textboxes.

Comment: @Ed Swangren: Oh you're right. I thought there was an implicit equality operator defined on `WebControl` class that would use this attribute. Looking at code I can see there is none. `DefaultProperty` is only used in design time direct typing.

Comment: @Robert: *equality* operators do not assign values. They compare for equality. And you cannot define *assignment* operators in C#. It's just unfortunate that both use the "equals" symbol.

Comment: @Ed: Sorry. I meant implicit assignment operator. As in `public static implicit operator WebControl(string value)` but never mind. It's not implemented so doesn't work anyway.

Comment: That actually wasn't me that time ;)

Comment: @Robert: That is the implicit *conversion* operator. Like I said before, you cannot define *assignment* operators in C#. Sorry for picking nits...

Comment: @Ed: sorry. @Martinho: You're right. I am writing this in a quick manner without checking the actual official wording. I think we both know what I mean and that it would be possible. But is not implemented.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Linq...

```
Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().ForEach(tb => tb.Text = "");
```

Comment: That's a clever one liner to clear them all. Clearing controls? there's a lambda for that!

Comment: You could also use a real `foreach` and avoid a pointless creation of a list.

Comment: For that matter, isn't `.ForEach()` an extension on `Enumerable`, which `OfType()` returns? Wouldn't the same statement work without the `ToList()` call? :)

Comment: @djacobson No, the foreach is a List<T> thing...however its trivial to create a foreach extension for IEnumerable<T> (in my real code base I have done so) and you probably see it all the time in examples, so it just seems that it is a supplied extension.

Comment: @Martinho, sure, but this is more fun ;-)

Comment: @Tim Jarvis You're right, which disturbs me, because apparently I'm dreaming about non-existent MSDN pages now. :P But this reminded me of an [interesting blog post about ForEach...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2009/04/08/why-i-don-t-use-the-foreach-extension-method.aspx)

Comment: @djacobson, a very interesting article. A little too black and white for my taste. His general premise is good though, generally you do want to avoid state transitions. I think though that in case's like this simple one that operates on GUI widgets is perfectly fine and makes for simple readable and maintainable code. I would (and do) constrain my extensions to the GUI namespace that specifically uses it.

Answer (score 1):

Looping through controls is always an option too...

```
foreach (Control objControl in this.Controls) 
{
     if (objControl is TextBox) 
     {
          ((Textbox)objControl).Text = String.Empty;
     }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer `if (objControl is TextBox)` for efficiency's sake.

Answer (score 1):

And this is another way

Is this what you want ?

```
foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
            if (item.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                ((TextBox)item).Text = "";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

People have given some good alternatives and comments, but let me address the question of exactly *what* is going on in these lines of code.

Pardon me if this is too basic, but you *did* say you were just learning C#. :)

```
this.textBox1.Text = "";
this.textBox1 = this.textBox2 = this.textBox3 = this.textBox4;
```

First, understand that `textBox1`, `textBox2`, etc. are references to objects of type `TextBox` which are contained in your `Form`. Every `TextBox` has a property called `Text` that is of type string. If I understand correctly, you'd like to clear the text from all four textboxes on your form, which is to say **you want to set the value of the `Text` property for each `TextBox` to the empty string `""`.**

Your first line of code does this, but only for the first `TextBox`. The second line of code, however, as others have pointed out, assigns each `textBox<n>` reference to refer to the same `TextBox` as `textBox4`. If `textBox4.Text` happens to be the empty string, this will *appear* to do what you want, but in reality you've changed the state of the references to the `TextBoxes` themselves, and not the values in **each `TextBox`'s `Text` property.**

Make sure you understand the difference between setting a reference (`textBox1 = textBox2`) and setting a *property* (`textBox1.Text = textBox2.Text`). In the first case, you went from having references to two TextBoxes to having two references *to the same TextBox.* To simply clear out TextBoxes, you want the second case, which merely copies the property value.

In short, given that (hopefully not-too-muddled) explanation, your code as given should become this:

```
this.textBox1.Text = "";
this.textBox4.Text = this.textBox3.Text = this.textBox2.Text = this.textBox1.Text;
```

**But, strictly speaking, you're much better off** using a solution like [@Tim Jarvis's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522061/how-does-this-work-with-textboxes-in-win-forms/4522246#4522246) or [@Brandon's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522061/how-does-this-work-with-textboxes-in-win-forms/4522230#4522230), which work regardless of how many TextBoxes you have on your form.

Good luck! :)

Comment: A correction: assigning the same reference to all of the textbox variables will actually *not* clear the text either.  This is because the TextBoxes belong to the Form's Controls collection.  The fact that textBox2 now points to the same thing as textBox1 is irrelevant because these are simply copies of references.  The textboxes displayed on the form are still all separate instances.